# I have make a html form in which I click on add button and a new row come. I want I want to get total amount of all rows

Tags: javascript, html

I make a page in which when I click on the button it makes a row. In row I store quantity and cost and total. Now I want to make a function that calculates the sum of all rows total and when I input paid value it subtracts from total amount and shows in grand total textbox.
Here is html code:

```
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    
      <thead>
        
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Item Name</th>
        <th>Batch No</th>
        <th>Remarks</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Cost Per Piece</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </thead>
        

    <tbody id="tbody">
   

</tbody>
<center><button type="button" name=""  onclick="additem()" class="btn btn-success"> Add</button></center></td>

<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><h3 style="color:red;">Total Amount</td>
     <td><input type="number" id="totalamount" class="form-control" name="text" readonly /></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td> </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><h3 style="color:red;">Miscellaneous</td>
    <td><input type="number" name="paid" id="paid" class="form-control" /></td>
  </tr>  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td> </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><h3 style="color:red;">Paid</td>
     <td><input type="number" name="paid" id="total10"  class="form-control" /></td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td> </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><h3 style="color:red;">G.T.Balance</td>
     <td><input type="number" name="" id="gtotal" class="form-control" readonly /></td>
  </tr> 

 
        </table>
```

And Javascript code is

```
let x = 0;
function additem() {
x++;
  var html=`<tr;
      <td><center>${x}</center></td>
      <td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='product_name'></td>
      <td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='batch_no'></td>
      <td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='remarks'></td>
      <td><input id='qty${x}' type='number' class='form-control' oninput='calculate(${x})'  id='qty' name='total_qty'></td>
      <td><input id='cost${x}' type='number' class='form-control'  oninput='calculate(${x})' id='cost' name='cost'></td>
      <td><input type='number' class='form-control'   id='total${x}'  name='total' readonly></td>
      <td><button type='button' id='btn' class='btn btn-danger'><i class='fa fa-remove'></i></button></td>
      </tr>`; 
      document.getElementById("tbody").insertRow().innerHTML= html;

}

function calculate(x) {
  const qty = document.getElementById(`qty${x}`).value;
  const cost = document.getElementById(`cost${x}`).value;
  const totalElem = document.getElementById(`total${x}`);
  totalElem.value = qty * cost
}
```

Now help me to make a function that sum totals of all rows and put in total amount then subtract with value of paid and show in G Total.

Comment: You cannot have content, such as `<center><button type=.....` where it is currently. It must be within a table cell

Comment: i want on front end first

Comment: The above HTML is not valid.. and please clarify `"i want on front end first"`

Comment: means when the first button click a row will come in that row we have quantity and cost and total when i enter cost and quantity it give me total but not i want total amount of all all rows in totalamount textbox

Comment: ID attributes must be unique - so adding new rows with the same IDs (`qty`, `cost` ) is not valid. An element can only have a single ID

Answer (score 0):

First of all, welcome to Stack Overflow. Now, about your question:

In order to make it work I made a few modifications on your HTML code and added a javascript function, which in my testing worked, but if they ever fail, please contact me and I'll try to fix them.

HTML:

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Item Name</th>
        <th>Batch No</th>
        <th>Remarks</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Cost Per Piece</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="tbody">
        
    </tbody>
    <center><button type="button" name="" onclick="additem()" class="btn btn-success"> Add</button></center>
    </td>

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <h3 style="color:red;">Total Amount
        </td>
        <td><input type="number" id="totalamount" class="form-control" name="text" readonly /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td> </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <h3 style="color:red;">Miscellaneous
        </td>
        <td><input type="number" name="paid" id="paid" class="form-control" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td> </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <h3 style="color:red;">Paid
        </td>
        <td><input type="number" name="paid" id="total10" oninput="calculateTotal()" class="form-control" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td> </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <h3 style="color:red;">G.T.Balance
        </td>
        <td><input type="number" name="" id="gtotal" class="form-control" readonly /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```js
function calculate(x) {
  const qty = document.getElementById(`qty${x}`).value;
  const cost = document.getElementById(`cost${x}`).value;
  const totalElem = document.getElementById(`total${x}`);
  totalElem.value = qty * cost
  calculateTotal()
}

function calculateTotal() {
  let fields = document.getElementsByName('total')
  let total = 0
  fields.forEach(f => {
    total = total + parseInt(f.value)
  })
  document.getElementById('totalamount').value = total
  let paid = document.getElementById('total10').value || 0 // If you change the  id of the "paid" field, change it here too.
  let subtotal = total - parseInt(paid)
  
  document.getElementById('gtotal').value = subtotal
}
```

Also, I don't know if the `total10` in the `paid` field is supposed to be there (you might want to limit the row number to 10), but I recommend you giving it a unique ID and changing it in the code, as I indicated with the comment.

Comment: sir here in the above calculate function i use id

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think I understood your question.
The calculateTotal function does not require any ID as it fetched the rows using the "total" field, which I fetch using the name "total"

Answer (score 0):

I try to adjust your code as little as possible, so you can basically use it directly

I did a few things

---

**First thing**

In your additem function, add a custom class attribute to the Total field

Originally

```
<input type='number' class='form-control'....
```

Replace with

```
<input type='number' class='form-control row-total'...
```

This is for the convenience of counting all the amounts at once, I will explain later

---

**Second thing**

I added the totalAmount function, which will find all the fields with custom class names just now, and run back and forth to add up all the money

It should be noted that when I create the totalAmount function, I put it into the calculate function, so that whenever you calculate the amount of the current column, the total amount of all columns will be calculated at the same time

---

**Third thing**

Since there is still need to calculate how much to pay and calculate with the total amount, a refreshTotalAmount function is established here, which will take out the total amount, and the payment amount for simple calculations, and establish an imput listener, whenever a payment is made When the amount changes, it will call the refreshTotalAmount function to refresh the total amount

---

```js
let x = 0;

function additem() {
    x++;
    var html = `<tr;
      <td><center>${x}</center></td>
      <td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='product_name'></td>
      <td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='batch_no'></td>
      <td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='remarks'></td>
      <td><input id='qty${x}' type='number' class='form-control' oninput='calculate(${x})'  id='qty' name='total_qty'></td>
      <td><input id='cost${x}' type='number' class='form-control'  oninput='calculate(${x})' id='cost' name='cost'></td>
      <td><input type='number' class='form-control row-total'   id='total${x}'  name='total' readonly></td>
      <td><button type='button' id='btn' class='btn btn-danger'><i class='fa fa-remove'></i></button></td>
      </tr>`;
    document.getElementById("tbody").insertRow().innerHTML = html;

}

function calculate(x) {
    const qty = document.getElementById(`qty${x}`).value;
    const cost = document.getElementById(`cost${x}`).value;
    const totalElem = document.getElementById(`total${x}`);
    totalElem.value = qty * cost;
    totalAmount();
}

function totalAmount(){
    let sum = 0;
    const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('row-total');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(el) {
        sum += parseInt(el.value);
    });
    document.getElementById("totalamount").value = sum;
    
}

function refreshTotalAmount(){
  const paidCash = document.getElementById("total10").value;
  const totalCash = document.getElementById("totalamount").value
  document.getElementById("totalamount").value = totalCash - paidCash;
}

document.getElementById("total10").oninput = function() {
  refreshTotalAmount(); 
}
```

```html
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
      <thead>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Item Name</th>
          <th>Batch No</th>
          <th>Remarks</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Cost Per Piece</th>
          <th>Total</th>
          <th>Action</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="tbody">
      </tbody>
      <center><button type="button" name="" onclick="additem()" class="btn btn-success"> Add</button></center>
      </td>
      <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>
              <h3 style="color:red;">Total Amount
          </td>
          <td><input type="number" id="totalamount" class="form-control" name="text" readonly /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td> </td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>
              <h3 style="color:red;">Miscellaneous
          </td>
          <td><input type="number" name="paid" id="paid" class="form-control" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td> </td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>
              <h3 style="color:red;">Paid
          </td>
          <td><input type="number" name="paid" id="total10" class="form-control" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td> </td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>
              <h3 style="color:red;">G.T.Balance
          </td>
          <td><input type="number" name="" id="gtotal" class="form-control" readonly /></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
```

You can Run code snippet to see if the result is what you want, if I did not misunderstand you

In addition, it is recommended that when designing dynamic grammar, elements should be careful not to repeat ID
And strict check of the field value, if this is not for your own use,

I didn’t specifically mention it in the article because
It will blur the focus. You are asking a question, and I am solving it. If I negate the adjustment of your entire code, it will be meaningless, so I am only raising it now.

Also, welcome to stackoverflow

Have a good day :)